# Asking latex to try harder to not split inline math across multiple lines

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, inline

I do not like it when my inline math gets broken up over multiple lines.
I'll live with it when I have to, but I'd rather it didn't happen,
even if this means sometime justification is a bit worse.
I wish to communicate this to latex.

If it were words, I would set the `\hyphenpenalty` to something larger.
I am not sure if that would apply to math or not,
but in any case I don't want to change it for words, just for math.

#### Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{3.8cm}
    Recall that the meaning of
    $P( w_j \mid w_i)$  is actually  that 
    $P(W_j{=}w_j \mid W_i {=} w_i)$.
    By not using softmax, with its normalising denominator this means that we expect that:
    $\sum_{\forall w_j \in V} P(w_j \mid w_i) \neq 1$ (except by coincidence).
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

#### Outputs:

[image: Not Great output]

which is not great,  see how that math which could fit on one line is broken on to two?

#### Better if I manually line break it:

[image: Better but still not great]

(Better still is possible with a bit of rewording but that is beyond latex's capacity :-D)

Comment: I think you shouldn't use inline math in these cases. Add `\displaystyle` to the summation at least. I guess these are margin notes but then this means it is not a note for the margin if it has that much math in it

Comment: @percusse ["I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this, which contains too much math for this margin to contain in good style"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)

Comment: see what happened for a few centuries, take away message don't do it

Answer (score 7):

You can place in a box that which you don't wish to allow to be broken apart. Of course, that is manual intervention, but may be the best in the circumstance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{3.8cm}
    Recall that the meaning of
    \mbox{$P( w_j \mid w_i)$}  is actually  that 
    \mbox{$P(W_j{=}w_j \mid W_i {=} w_i)$}.
    By not using softmax, with its normalising denominator this means that we expect that:
    \mbox{$\sum_{\forall w_j \in V} P(w_j \mid w_i) \neq 1$} (except by coincidence).
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that content in a box will not be subject to any expansion or compression based on margin constraints.  So, if the `\mbox` were removed from the first math object, internal math spacing would be adjusted to conform to margin constraints.

Clip:

[image]

**ALTERNATIVELY**, the use of `\nobreak` can also be used to manually prevent a break in math.  Here, a single addition of `\nobreak` after the `\mid` in the 2nd math element fixes everything....for the moment.  But add another word here or there, and you will have to re-intervene.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{3.8cm}
    Recall that the meaning of
    $P( w_j \mid w_i)$  is actually  that 
    $P(W_j{=}w_j \mid\nobreak W_i {=} w_i)$.
    By not using softmax, with its normalising denominator this means that we expect that:
    $\sum_{\forall w_j \in V} P(w_j \mid w_i) \neq 1$ (except by coincidence).
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the meaning of "me-aning"? :-)

Comment: @Mico LOL, I hadn't seen that earlier.  It's all about "me" I guess.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Which TeX engine do you employ? I can't seem to replicate your screenshot, using either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX under MacTeX2017.

Comment: @Mico just standard `pdflatex`.

Comment: good grief!  "standard" pdflatex doesn't hyphenate "me-aning"! when i just tested it, `\showhyphens{meaning}` produced `mean-ing".  and that's the same break i got when trying your example code.  so something else is going on here.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I would be happy to run whatever test you deem fit.  Where would the result of `\showhyphens{meaning}` show up?  It results in no output in the document.   The log gives this: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--9
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Recall that the me-
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1895) in paragraph at lines 4--9
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a-ning of $\OML/cmm/m/it/10 P\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10
w[] \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 j \OML/cmm/m/it/10 w[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )$`

Comment: @barbarabeeton also this: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 11--11
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 me-a-ning[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Recall that the me-
 []`

Comment: @barbarabeeton If I add `\hyphenation{mea-ning}` to the preamble, it also fixes it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Please make that `\hyphenation{mean-ing`}`.

Answer (score 6):

Automatic line breaking in math mode is governed by the parameters `\relpenalty` and `\binoppenalty`. Breaks are possible only after relation symbols or binary operation symbols, or at explicit penalties inserted by the user.

You can completely inhibit automatic line breaking by setting (maybe locally to a group)

```
\relpenalty=10000
\binoppenalty=10000
```

and later you can specify a feasible line break with `\linebreak` or `\nolinebreak` along with a suitable optional argument.

If you set values less than 10000, you make line breaks less desirable. The default values are 500 and 700 respectively.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{3.8cm}%\RaggedRight
    Recall that the meaning of
    $P( w_j{\mid}w_i)$ is actually that
    \mbox{$P(W_j{=}w_j{\mid}W_i{=}w_i)$}.
    By not using softmax, with its normalising denominator this means that we expect that:
    \mbox{$\sum_{\forall w_j \in V} P(w_j{\mid}w_i) \neq 1$} (except by coincidence).
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

use  justified environments in narrow environments lead to not good looking solution. see if use of `RaggedRight` from `raged2e` package is acceptable :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{3.8cm}\RaggedRight
    Recall that the meaning of
    $P( w_j{\mid}w_i)$ is actually that
    \mbox{$P(W_j{=}w_j{\mid}W_i{=}w_i)$}.
    By not using softmax, with its normalising denominator this means that we expect that:
    \mbox{$\sum_{\forall w_j \in V} P(w_j{\mid}w_i) \neq 1$} (except by coincidence).
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I can think of is to insert the directive `\raggedright` at the start of the `minipage`. In a narrow column, trying to fully justify the material is likely to produce rather large and unattractive interword gaps. Best to give up on justification by invoking `\raggedright`, which also suppresses hyphenation -- and the line-breaking inside inline math material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3.8cm}
    \raggedright
    Recall that the meaning of
    $P(w_j \mid w_i)$  is actually  that 
    $P(W_j=w_j \mid W_i = w_i)$.
    By not using softmax, with its normalising denominator 
    this means that we expect that:
    $\sum_{\forall w_j \in V} P(w_j \mid w_i) \neq 1$ 
    (except by coincidence).
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```