# Allow Latex to hyphenate words with dashes

Tags: hyphenation

I know from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380613/hyphenat-not-hyphenating-words-with-hyphens) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193307/how-do-i-get-latex-to-hyphenate-a-word-that-contains-a-dash) question that LaTeX won't hyphenate a word that already contains a hyphen.

This can be circumvented by using the `extdash` package that provides a special replacement that can be used instead of a hyphen that won't stop the word from being hyphenated.

My question now is whether it is possible to make normal hyphens behave in that exact way. I don't want to have to write all my hyphens in a special way. Instead I want LaTeX to apply that behavior automatically (unless I use a special hyphen-command for that exact purpose).

Is this doable? And if yes: How?

Comment: If there was a way to do this on all TeX engines, then the package you mention (`extdash`) would have probably got this feature already. Anyway, the thing you ask for is probably doable with LuaTeX, with no downsides. You can read the LuaTeX manual and give it a shot. :-)

Comment: With LuaTeX? Nice that's exactly what I'm using anyways! Will I find it in the manual directly or do I have to search for a specific keyword other than "dash" and/or "hyphenate"? :)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364550/2388 for a solution with \defaulthyphenchar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Traditional typographical practice is to avoid hyphenating such words, so such a rule was coded by Knuth into the TeX program.

However, it is still possible to insert a hyphen that allows breaks, by fooling TeX into thinking we have two separate words (by inserting empty glue). This can be quite easily done if we're willing to type a special sequence like `\Hyphdash` or `\-/` instead of a hyphen, which is what is provided by packages like `extdash`. But if we insist on typing regular hyphens into the TeX file, then “classical” TeX engines (meaning, other than LuaTeX) provide only one way of having regular hyphens be treated as something else, and that is to change the catcode of `-` to active, so that it becomes a macro that expands to something longer. But this would cause problems whenever `-` is used anywhere other than regular text, which is quite common (see examples of the problem in Steven's answer). I imagine that if a good solution existed for this in the classical TeX world, some package like `extdash` would have covered it.

(Actually, there's a perfectly sensible approach which for some reason is not very popular in the TeX world: and that is to preprocess your input file with some “smart” external script, replacing only the hyphens that occur in regular text with `\Hyphdash` (or its expansion) or whatever. But for some reason, people want to do everything inside TeX.)

With LuaTeX, which allows greater access to TeX internals, a lot of things become possible, and a lot of catcode and macro-related headaches are gone. For example, LuaTeX has a `hyphenate` callback which can be used to modify the regular hyphenation it does. This callback gets a list of nodes, into which we can insert discretionary nodes (hyphens) wherever we choose. This is much easier than having to do everything with macros (it is hard to set up appropriate input which later expands into exactly what we need, with no other interference). And there's even a `lang.hyphenate` function, which we can use to simply do what the regular hyphenation does.

The following seems to work: put the following in a file, say `hyphenateall.lua`:

```lua
function hyphenate_always(head, tail)
   local n = head
   while n do
      if node.type(n.id) == 'glyph' and n.char == string.byte('-') then
         -- Insert an infinite penalty before, and a zero-width glue node after, the hyphen.
         -- Like writing "\nobreak-\hspace{0pt}" or equivalently "\penalty10000-\hskip0pt"
         local p = node.new(node.id('penalty'))
         p.penalty = 10000
         head, p = node.insert_before(head, n, p)
         local g = node.new(node.id('glue'))
         head, g = node.insert_after(head, n, g)
         n = g
      end
      n = n.next
   end
   lang.hyphenate(head, tail)
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback('hyphenate', hyphenate_always, 'Hyphenate even words containing hyphens')
```

and just put `\directlua{require('hyphenateall')}` in your `.tex` file.

---

For example (borrowing the example from Steven's answer):

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
% Not needed -- used in this example just to show it's not needed :-)
\newcommand\?{\nobreak-\hspace{0pt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0in}
\hbox{Before:} often hungry Works: often\?hungry What about: often-hungry
\end{minipage}\hspace{1in}%
\directlua{require('hyphenateall')}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0in}
 \hbox{After:} often hungry Works: often\?hungry What about: often-hungry
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Note that after the `\directlua` call, we did not need the special syntax to get the extra hyphenation.

Comment: Why did `shower` not hyphenate?

Comment: Does `hyphenateall.lua` has to be located in the same directory as the `.tex` file or can it be put somewhere so that TeX will find it no matter which document it compiles?

Comment: @Raven Yes, the Lua file can be put somewhere that works for all documents, by (1) changing `dofile` to `require` (done in the answer), and (2) putting the file in a path that is looked up; see [answers to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/lua-tree-analogue-of-texmf-tree).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Actually, on my computer I don't get `shower` hyphenated with `pdflatex` either. So maybe I just have different hyphenation rules on my system, that are being used by both pdfTeX and LuaTeX.

Comment: It's weird.  It's the 2nd time I was questioned on the hyphenation performed by my LaTeX installation.  Apparantly, it also doesn't know how to hyphenate "meaning", https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415084/asking-latex-to-try-harder-to-not-split-inline-math-across-multiple-lines/415091#415091

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes So with `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \showhyphens{shower} \end{document}` I see `shower` in the terminal, not `sho-wer`. Same results on ShareLaTeX and Overleaf. Maybe you have set up different hyphenation patterns? (Anyway, changed to a better example, thank you!)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by changing the catcode of `-`, but that breaks all kind of stuff, since `-` is not only a dash but also a negative sign in math (as well as a dimensioning sign, as in `\kern-1pt`, `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`, `\rule[-1pt]{1pt}{3pt}`).

So this MWE below is a mere demonstration, not an actual recommendation.
Shown in the MWE for two zero-width `minipage`s, without then with active `-`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svdash-
{\catcode`-=\active %
\gdef-{\nobreak\svdash\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0in}
\catcode`-=12 %
First,
asteroid

Then,
shower

Last,
asteroid-shower
\end{minipage}\hspace{1in}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0in}
\catcode`-=\active %
First,
asteroid

Then,
shower

Last,
asteroid-shower
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Therefore, the better approach would be to (as noted for the `extdash` package), assign a special macro to be this special type of hyphen.  Here I choose `\?`, resulting in the identical output as the prior MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\?{\nobreak-\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0in}
First,
asteroid

Then,
shower

Last,
asteroid-shower
\end{minipage}\hspace{1in}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0in}
First,
asteroid

Then,
shower

Last,
asteroid\?shower
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to "change the catcode back" when entering math mode?

Comment: Sure, but negatives are used for dimensioning in all sorts of places outside of mathmode, e.g., `\kern-1pt`, `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`, `\rule[-1pt]{1pt}{3pt}`, etc.  It would be easier to just change the `\catcode` at the beginning of a block that you know is normal text, and turn it off at the end of the text block.

Comment: Ah yes of course... Totally forgot about those.

Comment: Why the `\nobreak` before and after the hyphen? Don't we want to allow breaks there (especially after the hyphen)?

Comment: Interesting: if the latter `\nobreak` is left out, then pdfTeX inserts a blank line for some reason. But if the `\nobreak` is kept, then LuaTeX honours it and does not break there. So neither option works in both engines!

Comment: The discrepancy between the engines is interesting (also, using `-\penalty0\hskip0pt\relax` as recommended at http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-nohyph.html gave wrong results in LuaTeX). May be a good question to ask on the site :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The `\hspace` is what allows the break,  And since I was using pdflatex, I noticed the blank line when removing `\nobreak`.  I did not realize there was an engine dependency. Thanks for noting that.

Comment: ^ I've asked a question about the above engine-dependency [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418001/what-explains-this-discrepancy-between-luatex-and-other-engines)